# Toggle visibility of UIBarButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I have created a application which has a view, tableview and a text view, I have setup my application in a way that when a user click on button log in view it takes them to tableview and clicking on a cell in table view takes them to textview. I have used only single xib for all these. Everything works fine. Now when I navigate to table view the UIBarButton has 3 button, Back to view(Left), Back to table view(Right) and a clear button(Right) and when I click on a cell in table view it goes to text view and all 3 button are still there. What I require is when the tableview appears the button Back to log should be hidden and other 2 should be visible and when I am on textview, Back to main and Back to log should be visible and clear button should be hidden. Is there a way to achieve this?? These are my codes for the UIBarButtons:

```
UIBarButtonItem *clearHistory=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Clear History" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(clearTable)];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnBack=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goBack)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=btnBack;

    UIBarButtonItem *btnBacklog=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back to log" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goBacklog)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:clearHistory,btnBacklog, nil];


- (void)goBack {
    self.tableLogView.hidden = YES;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
    self.viewLogToolbar.hidden=NO;
    self.extendedView.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)goBacklog {
    self.tableLogView.hidden = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
    self.viewLogToolbar.hidden=YES;
    self.extendedView.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)clearTable
{
    if([tableData count])
    {
    UIAlertView *message= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete All History" message:@"Are you sure?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Delete", nil];
        [message show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *message= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"No History" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code like this: It doesn't hide but achieves the exact same function. I hope this is what u are expecting.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
   UIBarButtonItem *clearHistory=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Clear" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(clearTable)];
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=clearHistory;

   UIBarButtonItem *btnBack=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goBack)];
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=btnBack;



- (void)goBack {
   self.tableLogView.hidden = YES;
   self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
   self.viewLogToolbar.hidden=NO;
   self.extendedView.hidden = YES;

}

- (void)goBacklog {
   self.tableLogView.hidden = NO;
   self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
   self.viewLogToolbar.hidden=YES;
   self.extendedView.hidden = YES;

   [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Clear" ];
   [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(clearTable)];
}
```

Put this code inside function where u navigate from tableview to textview

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Back to log" ];
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(goBacklog)];
```

If you still want to keep 2 right buttons in array then only thing u can do is toggle the enable option between the two buttons like

```
UIBarButtonItem *ubi= [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems objectAtIndex:0];

ubi.enabled=NO/YES;
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I know I could count on you :)

Answer (score 0):

The `UIBarButton` doesn't have a `hidden` property.

The easiest way to show only the desired buttons is to dynamically change the `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` and `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` values. That is, each time you change screens, you set these values to the desired ones. If you want animations during the change, use the

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:actualBarButton animated: YES]
```

expression instead of the simple property assignment.